# Custom MongoDb docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker

I've created this Dockerfile in order to create an image:

```
FROM mongo:2.6
MAINTAINER Living Digital Way
COPY ./init.ms .
RUN mongo < ./init.ms
```

`init.ms` is like:

```
use fdb;
db.col.insert({"name": "name1"...});
...
```

As you can see I'm trying to add some data to my mongo instance.

When I'm building this image I get this message from Docker:

```
Step 4 : RUN mongo < ./init.ms
04:34:47 
04:34:47  ---> Running in 96dd54d94bc6
04:34:47 
04:34:47 MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12
04:34:47 
04:34:47 connecting to: test
04:34:47 
04:34:47 2016-09-07T08:34:47.482+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
04:34:47 
04:34:47 2016-09-07T08:34:47.483+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
04:34:47 
04:34:47 [91mexception: connect failed
04:34:47 [0m
04:34:47 ERROR: Build step failed with exception
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should start mongod at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start mongod at first.

```
FROM mongo:2.6
MAINTAINER Living Digital Way
COPY ./init.ms .
# assume you are in mongo bin directory
RUN mongod -f you-config-path/mongo.conf
RUN mongo < ./init.ms
```

Comment: I thought `mongod` was already running since official [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/fc91d681fa5808c30c3118ce7fe3f993beccc82d/2.6/Dockerfile) starts it. Since the base image starts the deamon I figured out it would be started, isn't it?