# Best strategy to backup mongodb docker instance?

Tags: mongodb, docker, backup

In the mongodb docker page there's the following tutorial on how to dump a mongodb collection:

```
sudo docker exec container_name sh -c 'exec mongodump -d collection_name --archive' > /home/mongo_backup/all-collections.archive
```

I thougth of creating another container which runs this dump periodically (twice a day for example) and saves to a folder that is mounted inside it. But can I `mongodump` from a container that is not the container that has the collections? Can I `mongodump` via local network?

After this is solved, there's still the problem of where to send this backup. It can't be on the same place as my code deployed because it can be erased accidentaly.

Is this a good backup strategy? Any better ideas?

Comment: Have you tried mapping the db to a external volume on your computer?  You should be able to remove and rebuild the container using that as a persistent volume and also backup that location.

Comment: @CoryC yes, the mongodb is mapped, but not to a specific directory, just a docker directory, I just gave it a name. I didn't bother to map to a file

Comment: You may create custom Dockerfile ([Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39365267/3710490) + [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)) and schedule mongodump. Or, `volume` mongodb binaries to your local directory, create separate `cron` container and give access to MongoDB binnaries

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I thougth of creating another container which runs this dump periodically [...] there's still the problem of where to send this backup

[`mgob` - *"MongoDB dockerized backup agent"*](https://github.com/maxisam/mgob) does just that: it's a container running `mongodump` periodically with features to upload generated dump to various Clouds, S3 and SFTP.

We've been using it for some time both with Docker and Kubernetes with good results.

Comment: What is the advantage of having a container for backing up as opposed to cronttab running the mongodump from the host into the container running mongo and creating the archive directly on the host filesystem? Thanks

Comment: It gives you more control over your backup process. With cron you'll basically run a shell command, probably `mongodump` + some kind of upload to backup server. It's fine in simple situations, but how about logging? Error handling? Scalability? Tools like mgob + Docker let you have standardize logging, proper error handling and multiple features without too much boiler plate. In short, don't reinvent the wheel :) However if your need is simple enough you may not have to build such complexity and good old cron is ample enough.

Answer (score 1):

To Backup a MongoDB in the docker instance manually ( without creating another container )

You can do the following :

**Backup MongoDB data**

Login to the server ( if running locally you don't need this)

Run this command:

> docker exec old-docker-mongodb-1 sh -c 'mongodump --archive' > db.dump

(This will create a db.dump file)

(replace old-docker-mongodb-1 with your docker container name)

**Copy db.dump to your local** ( you might not need this)

```
scp orginalpath/db.dump /d/mybackup
```

**Restore mongoDB data to a docker continer**

```
docker exec -i new-docker_mongodb_1 sh -c 'mongorestore --archive' < db.dump
```